# How to get posts by compare 2 custom fields value?

Tags: wordpress, compare, custom-fields

I have "product" custom post type. It have 2 custom fields: price1, price2 (price of product)
I want to get all posts have price1 < price2 (compare 2 values)

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice sample that should help you out:

```
$args = array(      
    'tax_query' => array(
           'taxonomy' => 'custom_taxonomy_name',
        array(
            'key' => 'price',
            'value' => array( 100, 200 ),
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
            'type' => 'numeric',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'description',
            'value' => 'round',
            'compare' => 'NOT LIKE'
        )
    )
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: sorry phil, you misunderstand me. I want to compare values of price1 meta key and price2 meta key. Don't compare value of price1 with some int value